# Java Postfix increment operator, order of evaluation

Tags: java, increment, postfix-mta, evaluation

I am really wondering about how a line of code gets executed using the postfix increment operator. 
So this is the context:

```
array[index++] = new Thing(index);
```

Let's say the array is empty, does this Thing get stored in array[0] or maybe even array[1] ?
So I know the basic difference between postfix and prefix but I wonder if the left side of the index call somehow gets evaluated earlier than the right if you know what I want to say.

Thanks a lot for every help I am really unsure about this.

Answer (score 0):

This will essentially come off as follows with postfix `index++`:

```
index = 0
array[0] = new Thing(1);
```

And with prefix `++index`:

```
index = 0
array[1] = new Thing(1);
```

Postfix essentially works by using the existing value of index and then incrementing it while prefix is increment-and-use.